# Flutter: Voice to Text

Tags: arraylist, text, navigation, flutter, voice-recognition

I want to say:

"***What is my Account Balance***"

Simple examples that convert the above voice into array like;

```
words = {
        [What]
        [is]
        [my]
        [Account]
        [Balance]
};
```

So, I can check the words and route to respective page.

```
switch (voiceToRoute) {
      case “Account”:
         Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new AccountPage()));
        },
        break;

      case “Balance”:
        Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new BalancePage()));
        },
        break;
    }
```

Can anyone provide a solution in Dart/Flutter about Voice to text?

Answer (score 3):

There's a speech recognition library available which may fit for your needs:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/speech_recognition

Comment: thanks. I try that one even I change "_currentLocale = 'en_US';" to tr_TR and dint work.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this API which converts Voice to Text. Here'a code you can use to implement in your flutter application.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.apyhub.com/stt/file');

  final req = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
    ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'file', 'sample.wav'))
    ..fields['language'] = 'en-US';

  req.headers['apy-token'] = 'SECRET-APY-TOKEN';
  req.headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

  final stream = await req.send();
  final res = await http.Response.fromStream(stream);
  final status = res.statusCode;
  if (status != 200) throw Exception('http.send error: statusCode= $status');

  print(res.body);
}
```

You can generate `secret-apy-token` from [here](https://apyhub.com/utility/speech-to-text) ( It's free and offer up to 2M API Calls in starter plan)